# Zookeeper for Data Storage?

Tags: service, apache-zookeeper, datastore

I want a external config store for some of my services , and the data can be in following format like JSON,YML,XML. The use case I want is that I can save my configs , change them dynamically , and the read for these configs will be very frequent. So, for this is `Zookeeper` a good solution. Also my configs are of atmost 500MB.

The reason that Zookeeper is under consideration as it has `synchronization property`, version (as I will be changing configs a lot) ,can provide notifications to the depending service of changes to config. Kindly tell if Zookeeper can be data store and will be best for this use case,any other suggestion if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Zookeeper may be used as data store but

1. Size of single node should not be longer than 1MB
2. Getting huge amount of nodes from zookeeper will take time, so you need to use caches. You can use Curator PathChildrenCache recipe. If you have tree structure in your zNodes you can use TreeCache, but be aware that TreeCache had memory leaks in various 2.x versions of Curator.

Zookeeper notifications is a nice feature, but if you have pretty big cluster you might have too many watchers which brings stress on your zookeeper cluster.

Please find more information about [zookeeper failure reasons](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/zookeeper-resilience-at-pinterest-adfd8acf2a6b).

So generally speaking Zookeeper can be used as a datastore if the data is organized as key/value and value doesn't exceed 1MB. In order to get fast access to the data you should use caches on your application side: see [Curator PathChildrenCache recipe](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/path-cache.html).

Alternatives are [Etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/) and [consul](https://www.consul.io)